# ¿Se puede insertar datos a una única columna en sql?

Tags: sql

Estoy trabajando con una tablas, cada una con su respectivo INSERT y todo lo necesarío. Pero me preguntaba si es posible que ingresará datos a una sola de las columnas de una tabla. Por ejemplo, yo tengo la siguiente tabla

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIES (
    CODESTUDIO NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    COD_PELI NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    NOMBREPELI VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    PRESUPUESTO NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    SUELDO NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
    DURACION NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    ACTOR VARCHAR2(20),
    GUIONISTA VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    CAMARA VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    DIRECTOR VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    CATERIN VARCHAR2(10),
    PRODUCTOR VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT COD_PELI_PK PRIMARY KEY (COD_PELI),
    CONSTRAINT PELIS_CODESTUDIO_FK FOREIGN KEY (CODESTUDIO) REFERENCES ESTUDIOS(CODESTUDIO)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

¿Si yo quisiera añadir un nuevo ACTOR (además del que ya puse)a una película que ya tengo creado sería posible?

Gracias!

Comment: A una sola no, desde el momento que declaras que tus columnas no pueden aceptar valores nulos

Comment: Sumado a lo que dice @BetaM, considera estudiar tablas relacionadas para tu modelo de datos

Comment: Tu problema es otro... si vos queres tener varios actores en una sola pelicula debes tener una tabla actores asociada a esta tabla... estudia sobre normalizacion de bases de datos

Comment: Grafias a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer un update al registro ya existente(para agregar el actor que necesitas),
si lo que requieres es que se agregen varios actores a una sola Movies(trata de usar singular en el nombre de tus tablas y de no combinar ingles con Español), entonces lo que yo haría seria crear una tabla hijo(Actor) y en esta agregaría una llave foránea para la tabla Movie.

Comment: Esa relación que planteas luce un tanto incorrecta, sería que en movies exista la llave foránea apuntando hacia usuario

Comment: La relación es M-N porque un actor puede estar en varias películas y una película seguro tendrá al menos un actor. Los comentarios al OP sobre revisar normalización son muy relevantes y no se resuelven con esta recomendación.

Comment: Buen punto alfabravo, la relación tendría que ser muchos a muchos(una película puede tener muchos actores y un actor puede actuar en muchas películas).

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de crear tu tabla estás indicando que los valores son NOT NULL (no nulos, no vacíos), esto indica que al momento de insertar un dato si o si tienes que llenar todos los campos que están con esta propiedad, ahora si declaras que los campos pueden ser nulos ya podrías insertar valores sólo en una columna, por ejemplo: insert into MOVIES(CAMARA) values('camara'). Espero sea de tu ayuda.